# Inference of traits in scala

Tags: scala, types, casting, traits, higher-kinded-types

I'm having trouble with type inference in scala. I'm using classes with higher-kinded types, which extend some traits; but the scala compiler can't resolve the types to the traits they extend. The minimal example is shown here:

```
trait traitA[X]
trait traitB[X]
class A[X] extends traitA[X] {}
class B extends traitB[C] {}
class C {}

val a = Seq[A[B]]()
val b: Seq[traitA[traitB[C]]] = a

Error: type mismatch;
  found   : Seq[A[B]]
  required: Seq[traitA[traitB[C]]]
    val b: Seq[traitA[traitB[C]]] = a
```

I can get a Seq[traitA[B]] but not a Seq[traitA[traitB[C]]].

What am I missing here?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Works with `Seq[A[traitB[C]]]()`, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to ask for covariance in `traitA` as follows:

```
trait traitA[+X]
```

And you'll get:

```
scala> val b: Seq[traitA[traitB[C]]] = a
res0: Seq[traitA[traitB[C]]] = List()
```

Why? because `A[X]` is a subtype of `traitA[X]` and you want to enforce that `Seq[A[X]]` is also a subtype of `Seq[traitA[X]]`.